# Send email with logic app but have a list of email addresses

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to automate sending emails. I want to read the email addresses from a list so people can add their email easy.  I know how to get the file but not how to get send an email 2 to read it.

Comment: Does this post answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I tried to send email from a file stored in Azure.

1. My File contents are stored in a static website which can be accessed over Curl/HTTP request. file format is as follows ( 1 email id per line )

   ```
      abc@gmail.com
      xyz@gmail.com
   ```
2. Add following logic app sequence
   [image]
3. Go to Code view and change following ( this is due to new line representation bug in logic app expression or maybe there is another way to specify newline )
   [image]

   4. To

[image]